# Cambiar formato de fecha que se muestra en una tabla html desde Base de Datos

Tags: php, mysql, sql

El formato de fecha extraida desde sql es 2019-09-10 lo que requiere es cambiar el formato de esa fecha a 10 Septiembre 2019.

En la base de datos el input de fecha está como date.

Éste es el código:

```
<?php
require_once 'conexion.php';
$result;
$conn = dbConnect();
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM date_prices'  
$result = $conn->query($sql);       
$rows = $result->fetchAll();    
?>
<div class="table-responsive">
<table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Dates</th>
                            <th>Public Prices</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
    <tbody>
    <?php
        foreach ($rows as $row) {   
    ?>

                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            <?php echo $row['date_start'];?> al <?php echo $row['date_end']; ?>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                        <?php echo $row['public_price']; ?>
                        </tr>

    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La respuesta que te han dado es muy válida. Otra alternativa que yo preferiría, personalemente, es atacar el problema directamente de la raíz y formatear la fecha en la propia query:

```
SELECT 
  DATE_FORMAT(campofecha, %d %M %Y),
  otros_campos
FROM date_prices
```

Así obtienes la fecha directamente formateada y sólo tienes que mostrarla por pantalla.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on bool (en esta línea $rows = $result->fetchAll();

Comment: Así funcionó correctamente $sql = 'SELECT DATE_FORMAT(start_date, "%d-%m-%Y") start_date, public_price FROM date_prices';  Gracias!

Answer (score 5):

Puedes valerte de la clase `DateTime()` para volver al `string` que pasas una instancia de dicha clase y poder a su vez utilizar el método `->format()` para construir la estructura de la salida que esperamos tenga.

```
$fecha = "2019-09-10";

$fechaNueva = new DateTime($fecha);

echo $fechaNueva->format("d F Y");
```

Dando como salida:

> 10 September 2019

- Usamos `d` para pedir el día del mes en formato numérico
- Usamos `F` para solicitar el nombre del mes considerando que este originalmente saldrá en inglés
- Usamos `Y` para solicitar el valor del año

Comment: +1 a tu respuesta, otra opción seria usar `date()` junto con `strtotime`